# django modelform BooleanField checkbox

Tags: django, checkbox, boolean, modelform

I have a model with a BooleanField

model.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    test = models.BooleanField()

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
```

view.py

```
def registreren(request):
    context = {'form': TestForm()}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TestForm(request)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("test.html", context)
```

test.html

```
<body>
        <form action="/registreren/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}
                <input type="submit" value="Hit it!" />

        </form>
</body>
```

when I save the form I only get false values even if I click the checkbox in the form. So either if the checkbox is clicked or not in the form all instances of Entry.test are False.

I have no idea what goes wrong. All other values are send correctly.

Comment: We'll have to see your view code and your template code. I can only hope you have an error in your template code if the rest of the values are being sent correctly..

Comment: Added view and template code. It´s really simple test code that should work. By the way it's django 1.4

Comment: your problem is simple: you are not passing any data to your form... see answer

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the request object to the form instead of the request.POST dictionary-like object which contains your POST data.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = TestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

I thought you said the other fields are showing up? They shouldn't!